# Is there a 'Mathematics' Stack Exchange-like editor with an option to save drafts?

Tags: discussion, editor, mathjax

I really like the ease of use to type [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) and general text in the *[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)* text editor. I was wondering if the same editor has been implemented somewhere else where someone could use it for typing general drafts and not queries addressed to people online.

For example, I often need to type my solutions for questions in the *Mathematics* editor, screenshot the preview, and send it to my teacher, since it's a lot more comfortable to use than true LaTeX editors, like [Overleaf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overleaf), and I lack the time to get accustomed to one. But I don't have the ability to save drafts, and edit them later on once I close the site. Is there an alternative for this purpose?

I did think of copying my drafts to a text file, and then accessing them again later if I need to, but that too feels inconvenient.

Comment: Perhaps this is more appropriate on [math.meta.se]… Here is one old post on the [math.se] main site that may be of use: [Online MathJaX editor](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/276104). There seem to be several related posts on the meta site, for instance [MathJax WYSIWYG Editor](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12967), [Latex editor suggestion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5053), and other posts linked therein.

Comment: But the editor doesn't support LaTeX or [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)(?). Is it about the preview functionality?

Comment: I feel like the users at [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) would know the answer to this; perhaps it's under the [mathjax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=mathjax) tag.

Comment: I see @TheAmplitwist, I was not aware of the existence of MathSE Meta. Thanks for these links, I went through them and got a lot of help. I believe I have a satisfying solution as the Sandbox as mentioned below in one of the answers and StackEdit. Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want something *exactly* like the Math SE editor, there's always [Sandbox for drafts of long, complex posts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4666) - as the title suggests, it's

> intended for saving drafts of long, complex posts, especially posts whose composition takes a long time. It serves to localize to one thread the front-page "bumps" caused by edits to drafts of such posts, so that they may be easily ignored. Also, it helps to guard against losing longly-composed posts due to system crashes.
>
> When you are happy with your draft here, you may simply copy the code and paste it to the desired location.

Please carefully read the rules of use, explained in the quote block of the linked meta post.

Disclaimer: I'm not a Math SE member, just a random person who likes reading other sites' metas. Thus I don't know how they'd look upon someone using the sandbox for a stuff not intended for main-site. However, there tend to be plenty of empty answers so you shouldn't be blocking more typical usage of their sandbox.

Comment: There's another [Formatting Sandbox post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/370) that might work better for this purpose because the OP can post their own answer(s) there.